# How can I force Resharper to use the CLR type names for auto-generated code?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, naming-conventions, resharper

According to the [General Naming Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx) the usage of CLR type names (e.g. `String`,  `Int16`) should be preferred over the usage of language specific type names (`string`, `short`). I usually follow this advice. Resharper however seems to use the language specific type names when generating code (refactorings like extract method, generating foreach loops, etc.) which is very annoying.

How can I force Resharper to use the CLR type names instead?

*Update*
As many are wondering why someone would enforce a style where `Int32` instead of `int` or `String` instead of `string` is used, the intention was better syntax highlighting: int is rendered as a keyword, Int32 is rendered as a type. As modifying the highlighting implementation seems overkill, enforcing CLR type simply does the job. That one of the reasons why this is part of our style guide.

Comment: The link states that the CLR type names should be used for type names (e.g. method names). It doesn't mention anything about using these for for loop variables

Comment: Interestingly, StyleCop recomends otherwise and says to [use langauge specific type names](http://stylecop.soyuz5.com/SA1121.html) instead.

Comment: @flipchart I'm not talking about the name of the loop variable. Consider a `Int16[] numbers;`. Now I type `fore`, hit crtl-space enter and Resharper generates something like `foreach(var number in numbers){` and I have to choose between `var` and `short` for the type of `number`. In most cases `var` is totally okay but sometimes  I like to use the concrete type. I cannot overwrite `short` to `Int16` without messing up the auto-generation mode. I could life with that - but extract method, generate property etc. should work. If R# would use CLR types, there would be no problem at all.

Comment: Is your question about `var` vs `short`, or `short` vs `Int16`?

Comment: @AakashM My question is about using CLR types over language specific type names (which are usuallay also keywords in that language). To answer your question: `short` vs `Int16`. As I already said, it's very annoying to find (auto generated) extracted methods and generated properties not meeting the actual style guide.

Comment: @sehe yes, but the OP also explains this in terms of a convention document that *is being applied out of context*, so to understand the question we should also understand whether the correct thing is to fix the code vs to fix the misinterpretation of the referenced document.

Comment: @mbx the auto-generated code does neither **meet** the style-guide nor **fail to meet** the style-guide, because that style-guide ***does not apply itself*** to this situation.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you overtyping the type with `Int16` while in the `foreach` live template thingy. And as for R#-generated code, I very much doubt R# is going to help you write non-idiomatic C# (which appears to be your goal here)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Open R# Options, go to C# Code Style. Or in more detail:

`RESHARPER`->`Options`

`Code Editing`->`C#`->`Syntax Style`

`Build-in types`

- `In locals, members and parameters, prefer` - `CLR type name`
- `Members to qualify` - `CLR type name`

Aside: You probably want to safe it `Team Shared` only as most public projects prefer keywords instead (and you don't want to accidentally annoy OSS contributors by suggesting a patch with that style).

**older versions**

`Code Editing`->`C#`->`Code Style`

`Build-in type naming`->`When referencing build-in type, prefer using` choose `CLR type name`

[This feature requires R#9.1 or higher](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-5662).

**If you are bound to even older versions of ReSharper**

There was an Extension for R#4.5-5.1 with exactly that purpose in mind. It's called [Neovolve](http://neovolvex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20ReSharper%20Plugins%201.0&referringTitle=Home#). Unfortunately this extension wasn't ported to any later R# versions.

**VS 2015**

Also for Visual Studio 2015 you may want to disable to prefer the intrinsic predefined types (which causes the symbols to be grayed out in the text editor) under `Tools`->`Options` `Text Editor`->`C#`->`Code Style`->`Prefer intrinsic predefined type keyword*`

Answer (score 8):

Those guidelines are referring to public method names on your api, such as `obj.ReadInt32()` (perhaps in a serializer). In the body of a code (variables and parameters) it is less specified. Personally I prefer the aliases `double`, `int` etc - as:

- better highlighting
- less typing
- avoids issues with non-keyword usage, i.e. if I have another method/type/property/etc called `Int32` (stupid, but possible; where-as `int` always means `global::System.Int32`)
- works even if you don't have `using System;`

Personally, I would not worry about this. R# is not doing anything *wrong*.

As an aside - note that there are a few examples of MS getting this wrong - one that leaps to mind is `IDataReader`/`DbDataReader` with `GetFloat()` (should be `GetSingle()`).

Comment: not using System is a point. Better Highlighting? One reason for using CLR Types actually is highlighting: All types in same color, user defined types as well as languge types to not confuse them with other keywords. Less typing? Well, in most cases its just the same word with first letter uppercase. For `int` I prefer to know the length (must be an old habbit from using C on multiple platforms).

Comment: @mbx "most cases" ? 7 out of 15 are the same apart from capitals; 8 out of 15 are different - too close to say "most" either-way. For `int` you **do** know the length - it is **defined** as 4 bytes. Re "All types in same color" - that is subjective; personally I find it easier seeing them in keyword form - they *are* keywords, and *generally* your use of things like `int`/`bool` etc is not as fundamental to the code as your use of `SomethingIWrote` etc. I know I'm far from unique in this belief (see the Style Cop rule already cited).

Comment: @Marc_Gravell: "most cases" I use. Of course it's subjective, that's what style guides usually are. If you already have an established style guide in your company, the final task is to meet it, not to avoid it.

Comment: @mbx checking the R# "code cleanup" options, you *can* influence `var` vs explicit, but almost all tools will want to apply the far more dominant keyword usage, rather than your CLR-name usage.

Comment: This is very old but let me explain my down vote. First of all let me say that I respect your opinion. However, I feel that you haven't answered the question and your answer is partly based on personal preference.

Comment: @Jack pointing out that the OP is misreading/misinterpreting the CLR "General Naming Conventions" document is not opinion - which is the premise for the question; if the premise is wrong, it is questionable as to whether answering the question remains valid. Pointing out that MS has been inconsistent is not opinion. Where I have spoken about opinion, I used the word "personally" to make that clear. But as you will. I do appreciate taking the time to add reasons, at least.

Comment: Like I said before, I respect your opinions & I don't want to get into an argument. If I may, look at the question title and the 2nd paragraph, the question about R# settings. In your answer you have got caught up with the mention of CLR GNC. You mention R# once and basically tell the OP to get on with it and keep string rather than String. The OP wants R# to generate code as String. Whether that is a good idea or not is irrelevant. Anybody coming to this question wants the answer to the 2nd paragraph. You didn't give that answer.

Comment: @JackPettinger: Arguably, the OP wants R# to generate code as `String` *because of their interpretation of the CLR GNC*. As such, an explanation why that interpretation is incorrect and thus, the suggestion to leave things as they are appears fully appropriate. It is true that users finding this question may have a different reason to search for the same option, but that is at least in part a failure of the question as it is written, not of this answer.

Answer (score 4):

There is currently no ReSharper option to prefer `System.Int16` over `short`, and similar. There is an [open feature request on YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-5662) which you can vote for; but note that it has been open for over five years without being implemented, which you may choose to take as a hint.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question has already been answered, but for those wondering about the preferred style in the future, the .NET team now officially recommends using the language name instead of the CLR name, and this is the style used for .NET Core development.

> We use language keywords instead of BCL types (e.g. `int, string, float` instead of `Int32, String, Single`, etc) for both type references as well as method calls (e.g. `int.Parse` instead of `Int32.Parse`).

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/coding-guidelines/coding-style.md